# Does lightning bolt trigger wrath of the storm?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, reactions

A enemy [wizard](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard) cast [*lightning bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-bolt) while within five feet of a tempest domain [cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric).  The cleric inquired if the lightning bolt triggers the wrath of the storm feature since the enemy wizard was "attacking him."

Wrath of the Storm description says:

> When a creature within 5 feet of you that you can see hits you with an attack, you can use your reaction to cause the creature to make a Dexterity saving throw. The creature takes 2d8 lightning or thunder damage